# Bluetooth Master and Slave to track device's locations

Tags: programming, wifi, web-server, bluetooth, networking

I'm trying to create an app for my science fair that uses bluetooth to track people in a determined place.
I was thinking about one Arduino system to receive all the information and transmit through a network and some Arduino slaves to duplicate the signal and cover the hole place.

**Resuming...**

I'll have:

1. Arduino slaves placed all over the place to track people
2. One Arduino connected to the network to receive all the information from the slaves and pass it through the network.
3. Some kind of web app inside the main Arduino with an API to manage the data and make it friendly for third-party apps

I was wondering of what kind of equipment should I buy to make this happen. Thanks!

---

Each cellphone with it's bluetooth enabled will work as a person (sending signal) - my Arduino slaves will receive the signal (find bluetooth around it) and send the device name and signal strength to the arduino master - The arduino master (connected to the network) will interpenetrate the responses and send the results to the built-in web server - Apps will make requests to the web app to get this data and show in a plant where're these people.

Basically it will work like these bluetooth stickers that you can plug in to your keys, phone e etc... and with the app you can search for them in your house via bluetooth from your cellphone.

Here's a better explanation:
[Link](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/bluetooth-surveillance.htm)

Comment: Google "sensepost snoopy".  Also note that most phones are not discoverable unless they are put into pairing mode so you won't be able to detect them unless you already know their bluetooth ids in which case you can poll for them.

Comment: Classic bluetooth is not a solution for this.  BLE could be crudely, though signal-strength based positioning as commonly used there is only crudely accurate.  Time of flight measurement would require substantially better hardware than you have available.

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth generally support only one to one connection. Atmost 6 bluetooth can be connected to single module in latest bluetooth version(the basic model probably used by you connects only 1 device). Hence it is not a good idea to use bluetooth. Also if you need a web based platform you should switch to some more powerful platform like raspberry pi, beagle bone etc.